# Setting parent's height and width based on child dimension

Tags: typescript, react-native, layout

I need to set height and width of a View, based on height and width of his child. Is it possible?

I tried to use onLayout prop, but actually I didn't get the proper way to use it. Also, I was trying using measure method but refs are now deprecated on react-native 0.59.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native'

export default class myClass extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
               <View style={{}}>   //HERE I WANNA SET width and height of his child
                 <View>
                   <Text>Hello<Text>
                   <Text>Hello<Text>
                   <Text>Hello<Text>
                 </View>
               </View>
            </View>
        )
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using react with hooks (version `16.8` and above) this is done regularly through use of hooks. First create a useLayoutDimension hook like this:

```
import { useState, useCallback } from 'react'

export function useLayoutDimension() {
  const [dimension, setDimension] = useState(0)
  const layoutDimension = { width: 0, height: 0 }
  const onLayout = useCallback(({ nativeEvent }) => {
    layoutDimension.width = nativeEvent.layout.width
    layoutDimension.height = nativeEvent.layout.height
    if (dimension !== layoutDimension.width && layoutDimension.width > 0) {
      setDimension(layoutDimension)
    }
  }, [])

  return {
    dimension,
    onLayout,
  }
}
```

Then in the **Child** component do this:

```
import { useLayoutDimension } from 'app/hooks'

export const ChildComponent = (props) => {
  const { dimension, onLayout } = useLayoutDimension()

  useEffect(
    () => {
      props.getChildDimensions(dimension)
    },
    [dimension]
  )

  return (
    <View style={styles.ShadowWrapper} onLayout={onLayout}>
        {...content}
    </View>
  )
}
```

And in the **Parent** component you then set a piece of state to the dimension like this:

```
//...rest of the parent component
//Child below
<ChildComponent
    getChildDimensions={(dimensions) => {
        this.setState({
            dimensions: dimensions,
        })
    }}
/>
```

You can then set any other component in the parent component with the dimension state

```
<View style={{width: this.state.dimension.width, height: this.state.dimension.height}}
```

**Note:** This is using a combination of class and functional components (The child is functional and the parent is class). If you are not comfortable with these concepts [this](https://medium.com/@Zwenza/functional-vs-class-components-in-react-231e3fbd7108) will help. useState is the hook way of using this.state and useEffect is a hook that is fired at specific state changes. If you are unfamiliar with this a brief read on [hooks](https://medium.com/crowdbotics/build-a-react-native-app-with-react-hooks-5498e1d5fdf6) will help immensely.

**PS:** The first render will not have the dimensions as the state will need to be set. This is usually not noticeable however.

Comment: Also, my class was a modal and the child View was what the modal would have to render. This means I was setting states (isVisible state) in my child View. Splitting as you said means make my child View as a child component, but doing this I can't setState in my child component. Do you know how can I manage this? Maybe passing the isVisible variable as props from the parent to child? Is it possible when the child component is not a class?

Comment: Modal should not make a difference. The key is using the hook when the component has rendered. The isVisible state should only animate and reanimate the modal onto screen so no issues there. 

Keeping the dimension state in the parent and onLayout running a call back returning dimension information back up to the parent is the data flow you are looking for. No need to separate the two files. Combining the above exactly as shown should yield the right results (with the caveats I mentioned).
I use this regularly.

Comment: This hook is missing `dimension` and `layoutDimension` in its dependencies. Also, specifying `layoutDimension` as a dependency will cause onLayout to be recreated every render.